# How to update Angular 10+ routes with new lazy routes that come from the server?

Tags: angular, dynamic, routes, lazy-loading

I currently have a menu/profile system configured in the application's database.

What I'm trying to do is that, after logging in and with the menus loaded, I can then assemble the rest of the application's routes, filtering only the routes that the user has permission to access.

The problem with this approach I'm trying is that, each route is an Angular Module with slow loading, using loadChildren in the route configuration, and I believe this is what has given me problems.

This is my function that loads routes from the server and converts them into Angular route settings:

```
export const adminRoutifyDynamic = () => {
  // Array with the list of urls that the user is allowed to access
  const allowed = window['services'].cry.get('allowed', true);

  const routes = [];
  for (const subm of allowed) {
    const name = subm.split('/')[subm.split('/').length - 1];
    const module = startCase(camelCase(name)).replace(/ /g, '') + 'Module';
    const path = `../admin/${name}/${name}.module`;
    routes.push({
      path: name,
      loadChildren: () => import(path).then(m => m[module])
    });
  }

  return routes;
};
```

As you can see, I read the path of the route, break the path into pieces and with these I assemble the module's local path for that route.
And then I reconfigure the router through `resetConfig()`.

This function takes urls of type `/admin/games-config` and transforms them into
`{ path: 'games-config', loadChildren: () => import('../admin/games-config/games-config.module').then(m => m.GamesConfigModule) }`
(I don't include /admin in pathName because these routes are cofied as children of path /admin)

So far no problems or errors are issued, but I just try to access one of these new routes to receive the router error saying "Cannot match any routes".

On the other hand, I tried to do a test and took this same function and filled in manually some of the routes I get from the server, they are exactly the same paths and module names I get from the server, but since they are now hardcoded, they start working.

```
export const adminRoutifyDynamic = () => {
  // Array with the list of urls that the user is allowed to access
  // const allowed = window['services'].cry.get('allowed', true);

  const routes = [];
  // for (const subm of allowed) {
    // const name = subm.split('/')[subm.split('/').length - 1];
    // const module = startCase(camelCase(name)).replace(/ /g, '') + 'Module';
    // const path = `../admin/${name}/${name}.module`;
    // routes.push({
      // path: name,
      // loadChildren: () => import(path).then(m => m[module])
    // });
  // }
  routes.push({ path: 'games-config', loadChildren: () => import('../admin/games-config/games-config.module').then(m => m.GamesConfigModule) });
  routes.push({ path: 'challenges-config', loadChildren: () => import('../admin/challenges-config/challenges-config.module').then(m => m.ChallegesConfigModule) });
  routes.push({ path: 'posts', loadChildren: () => import('../admin/posts/posts.module').then(m => m.PostsModule) });

  return routes;
};
```

As you can see, the whole process is the same, the absolute paths and module names are the same, I just stopped mounting these paths inside the for..loop and now I bring them into a hardcoded array. From then on the process is the same, I call resetConfig() with these new routes and everything works fine, this rules out any problem with the resetConfig() method itself.

I'm beginning to suspect that if these lazy modules are not present in the code (physically) at Angular compile time, the routes are not recognized. This alone would explain the same module paths and their names working when they are hardcoded and not working when they come to server runtime.

The question now is: how to get around this problem?

Comment: APP_BOOTSTRAP_LISTENER you can use this with factory to give dynamic route name from server

Comment: @GaurangDhorda thanks for your comment but can you be more specific? When searching the web about APP_BOOTSTRAP_LISTENER I don't see this application for routing